# apt-add-repository not working on Ubuntu 13.04 set up on VMWare

Tags: networking, ppa, vmware

I have set up Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit as a virtual machine using VMWare Player. When I try to add the following repository I am getting an error. I have searched many articles to find an answer but every article out there talks about proxy. But I am not using any proxy, it is a simple virtual machine set up on VMWare.

This is the command I execute and the error message I get:

```
testuser@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome-team/gnome3
[sudo] password for testuser: 
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gnome-team/+archive/gnome3)
 to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the PPA is not correct.  To add the correct one, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Ahh man... I knew I was doing something wrong. Thank you so much Mitch :).